# Changing hover function to click/touch on Mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have content that is shown when a link is hovered upon for desktop/ laptops. **How can i change this to click for touch/ mobile devices as sometimes i need to double tab on the link to show the content?**

I am using the code below to identify if the user has touched the screen to change to a click function

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function onFirstTouch() {
// we could use a class
document.body.classList.add('user-is-touching');

// or set some global variable
window.USER_IS_TOUCHING = true;

// or set your app's state however you normally would
```

```js
$(".o-c").hover(function() {
  $('.home-o-c').show();
  $('.home-i-t').hide();
}, function() {
  $('.home-o-c').hide();
  $('.home-i-t').show();
});

$(".c-f").hover(function() {
  $('.home-c-f').show();
  $('.home-i-t').hide();
}, function() {
  $('.home-c-f').hide();
  $('.home-i-t').show();
});

$(".i-c").hover(function() {
  $('.home-i-c').show();
  $('.home-i-t').hide();
}, function() {
  $('.home-i-c').hide();
  $('.home-i-t').show();
});


$(".c-u").hover(function() {
  $('.home-c-u').show();
  $('.home-i-t').hide();
}, function() {
  $('.home-c-u').hide();
  $('.home-i-t').show();
});

window.addEventListener('touchstart', function onFirstTouch() {
  // we could use a class
  document.body.classList.add('user-is-touching');

  // or set some global variable
  window.USER_IS_TOUCHING = true;

  // or set your app's state however you normally would


  // we only need to know once that a human touched the screen, so we can stop listening now
  window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch, false);
}, false);


$(".o-c").click(function() {
  if ($('body').hasClass('user-is-touching')) {
    $('.home-o-c').show();



  } else {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".our-company").offset().top
    }, 2000);

  }
});

$(".c-f").click(function() {
  if ($('body').hasClass('user-is-touching')) {
    $('.home-c-f').show();
    $('.home-o-c').hide();
    $('.home-i-c').hide();
    $('.home-c-u').hide();
    $('.home-i-t').hide();



  } else {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".cf2").offset().top
    }, 2000);

  }
});
```

```css
.left-fill {
  background: #0000006b;
  height: 100vh;
}

.right-fill {
  background: pink;
  height: 100vh;
}

.vc_col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.pivot-nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-align: left;
}

.pivot-nav li a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.pivot-nav li a.default-underline::after,
.pivot-nav li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.pivot-nav:hover a.default-underline:not(:hover)::after {
  width: 0;
}

.pivot-nav li a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.home-o-c,
.home-c-f,
.home-i-c,
.home-c-u {
  display: none;
}

.our-company {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}

.cf2 {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="left-fill text-left wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">

    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <p class="home-i-t">TEXT One</p>
      <p class="home-o-c">TEXT One</p>
      <p class="home-c-f">TExt for C f.</p>
      <p class="home-i-c">Some more text fo i c.</p>
      <p class="home-c-u">Get in touch </p>

    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="home-fill right-fill text-right wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">

    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <ul class="pivot-nav">
        <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a class="o-c default-underline" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">O C</a></li>
        <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a class="c-f" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">C F</a></li>
        <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a class="i-c" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">I C</a></li>
        <li class="pivot-nav-item" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2"><a class="c-u" href="#">C U</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="our-company">
    Our Company Scroll Down

  </div>

  <div class="cf2">
    cf2 Scroll Down

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Do u want hover on Desktop and laptop and click on mobile?

Comment: Yes Hover on Desktop and laptop and click on Mobile as on desktop and Laptop it hover to show content and if clicked It scrolls down to the div. On mobile there is no scrolldown

Comment: Its fully javascript right? or shall i proceed in jquery?

Comment: jquery is better

Comment: can u plz send the entire code? can i modify ur code or add new code?

Comment: Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/m3vdp2xb/1/. jQuery and css code can be changed. HTML markup cannot

Comment: iam working local.. it will take some time.. surely i will send the code

Comment: have u added styles for mobile devices.. its looks same like desktop?

Comment: styling for mob will be added later. Just trying to get the functionality right i.e changing hover to click for hover

Comment: ok will update soon